# Pretty sick thing for monster vocalization, but I have a question

Tags: monster, voice, max-msp, reaktor

This guy has a pretty sick Max patch that he has for vocalizations. Check out [Dehumanizer Here.](http://orfeasboteas.com/dehumaniser/) Are there any max users that are able to pick that apart and possibly give some pointers as to how you can make that in reaktor? It looks like it has 4 pitch sliders and some spectral controls. It's hard to tell if the spectral fx are affecting the pitch sliders, or if they're just straight pitch. Even a screenshot of the patch would be cool. Enjoy to those that can use it!

Comment: Also, I forgot about the Max runtime. Non max owners can at least use the patch without editing capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time at the moment to download the patch, but looking at the video I think the "simple" implementation is using convolution where different "monster" impulse responses are chosen.  The advanced engine then just adds additional processing.  A bit of research of convolution should point you in the right direction.

BTW you can also create some good monster vocalisations with a vocoder and animal sounds.

Comment: Thanks bit, I've used that technique extensively in the past. This particular patch just includes like, all of the spectral processing and pitch elements that I would do to it to begin with. Huge time saver. Also, I totally forgot about the Max Runtime which allows you to run max patches. It's a little bit more than just convo. You gotta check it out, it's sick.

Comment: @Dave Oh yes....I'd also forgotten about the runtime. 

Answer (score 1):

If it's that good, don't forget to donate.......sound designers have got to earn a living ;-)

Comment: oh always. I'm going to be using this on this game, have to donate.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for sharing this.  very cool!